# Total from the count of two different tables

Tags: php, mysqli, count, html-table

I'm having a problem getting my results to behave properly. I have two queries, one for getting all the information of the clubs into the table, and another one to count the total members of each club in said table.

The problem is that the total numbers is displayed incorrectly, after the last cell on the table, not side by side like I'm aiming to display it.

Here's how it looks:

[image: table]
[image: table]

And here are my queries:

For the table

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombreClub, liderVoluntario, region, municipio, oficinaLoc
FROM club4h
ORDER BY region, oficinaLoc";
```

For the totals

```
    $sql = "SELECT count(soc.nombreClub)
            FROM socios  as soc
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN club4h as club
            ON soc.nombreClub = club.nombreClub
            GROUP BY club.id";
```

And the code of how i display the table

```
<table>
  <?php 
$name = '';
$filler = '';


echo '<tr>
<th>Regi&oacute;n</th>
<th>Unidad Program&aacute;tica</th>
<th>Nombre Club</th>
<th>Lider Voluntario</th>
<th>Localizaci&oacute;n Club</th>
<th>Total Socios</th>
</tr>';

foreach($result as $key=>$row){
echo'<tr>
<td>'.ucfirst($row['region']).'</td>';


if(($row['id']) !=$filler) echo 
'<td>'.ucfirst($row['oficinaLoc']).'</td>';
$filler = $row['id'];

echo '<td>'.ucfirst($row['nombreClub']).'</td>
<td>'.ucfirst($row['liderVoluntario']).'</td>
<td>'.ucfirst($row['municipio']).'</td>';
}

include_once 'sociocount.php';
foreach($memberSearch as $total){
echo '<td>'.$memberSearch[$i][0].'</td>
</tr>';
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Could this be done in a single query? Or what am I doing wrong that it causes it to be displayed like that?

Comment: Yes, you can do this in a single query. Basically it is - *SELECT SUM(`members`), `club` FROM `table` GROUP BY `club`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select everything in one query, here is example:

```
SELECT
    id,
    nombreClub,
    liderVoluntario,
    region,
    municipio,
    oficinaLoc,
    (select count(*) from socios as soc where soc.nombreClub=c.nombreClub) as memberCnt
FROM club4h as c
ORDER BY region, oficinaLoc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the idea and tried a similar query but was making a mistake in the FROM section of it. thanks again.